# a noun phrase mysteriously connected to the main clause

Tags: grammar

I saw the following sentence from a webpage about American diners, and I'm puzzled about the phrase "a few strong flavors and techniques". Grammatically, it is not linked to the preceding portion of the sentence; there's no preposition to do the job. How would you analyze it?

https://theawl.com/a-field-guide-to-the-true-american-diner-83393455d3e3#.jf379iyoi

The food is sturdy and simple, **a few strong flavors and techniques**.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It's an example of conversational deletion. You can retrieve the words in italics (or similar): << The food is sturdy and simple, _having_ a few strong flavors and _requiring a few simple cooking_ techniques. >> I'd say that this example is pushing it.

Answer (score -1):

As Edwin suggested, "having" would be better.

A better version of the original would be to replace the comma with a semi-colon:

> The food is sturdy and simple; a few strong flavors and techniques.